# cannot load a custom helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have wrote a `highlight helper` follow the [ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/).

app/helpers/highlight.js

`export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper( function(value, options) {
  var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="highlight">' + escaped + '</span>');
});`

I invoke the helper in the application template with `{{highlight name}}` and declare the `name` in application controller . When visit the index page I got this error
`Assertion Failed: A helper named 'highlight' could not be found`. Seems the helper is not loaded. Is there any configuration to load the helper ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you use ember-cli, as you tagged it this way.

Plain ember and ember-cli are using different resolvers (basiclly mechanisms that search for files in proper directories) and thus have a little bit different name conventions. Helpers in ember-cli [must have a dash in their name](http://www.ember-cli.com/#module-directory-naming-structure).

Take notice that if you only put the code you mentioned in your question, this file will have no information what is Ember. You still need to import Ember using modules. Very nice introduction can be [found here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules).

To sum up, change your helper file name to one that includes a dash and the helper will be recognized across the environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jakub. Yes, I use ember-cli in my application. I add a  dash to the helper ```high-light``` and invoke with ```high-light name``` .That works. Thanks.